# foursquare Invalid response

Tags: django, python-2.7, foursquare

My foursquare code was running fine all these days and suddenly it stopped working giving the following error message.
I am using the python foursquare wrapper [1]: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/foursquare/2014.01.18

```
ERROR:foursquare:Invalid response:
<html>
<head>
<title> ssl-cache-at51.hosts.fastly.net</title>
</head>
<body>
unknown domain: ssl-cache-at51.hosts.fastly.net</body></html>
ERROR:foursquare:Invalid response:
<html>
<head>
<title> ssl-cache-at50.hosts.fastly.net</title>
</head>
<body>
unknown domain: ssl-cache-at50.hosts.fastly.net</body></html>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: provide your requested parameters .

Comment: I tried putting client_id and client_secret, but it didn't work.

Comment: have u added version ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either:

- Your requests are going through some sort of ISP proxy that's jamming you up

or

- Foursquare is having issues on their end

ref:
https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare/issues/45